# PFUser.become returns Invalid session token

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to make an application in which users can switch to multiple accounts like Instagram. So when user login/signup I save their session token in UserDefaults. But when I switch to old account by calling PFUser.become and passing session token of the old user, I receive below error

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "Invalid session token"
```

Here is the code to save session token

```
var url : String?
            if PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: UserTable.Cols.PROFILE_PIC) != nil{
                url = (PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: UserTable.Cols.PROFILE_PIC) as! PFFileObject).url
            }
            
            let account = SwitchAccountDataItem(objectId: (PFUser.current()?.objectId)!,name: PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: UserTable.Cols.NAME) as! String, username: (PFUser.current()?.username)!, url: url, sessionToken: (PFUser.current()?.sessionToken)!)
            
            let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode([account])
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: UD_SWITCH_ACCOUNT_DATA)
```

And here is the code to switch account

```
PFUser.become(inBackground: mUsers[pos].sessionToken, block: {_,e in
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                if(e==nil){
                    self.delegate?.onAccountSwitched()
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else{
                    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Session expired")
                    self.mUsers.remove(at: pos)
                    let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(self.mUsers)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: UD_SWITCH_ACCOUNT_DATA)
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
```

mUsers is the array of SwitchAccountDataItem model

Comment: The same method is working for Android project. I don't understand why it does not work in iOS. Do I need to do some additional setup for retaining old sessions?

Comment: Have you added a break point at `PFUser.become(inBackground: mUsers[pos].sessionToken, block: {_,e in` and double checked the value of `mUsers[pos].sessionToken` and if this session token is still valid in the database?

Comment: Yes I have and the session token structure seems valid. But the session token is database are hidden so cannot confirm it.

Comment: You can check the session token using the dashboard api console. Try to send a get request to /me passing the session token in the header.

Comment: I checked the session has been deleted when another user logs in same device in iOS. But when I try same in Android, the new session is created every time and old one is not deleted. Hence, when I try ParseUser.become on previous user's session token in Android it works!!! The [Parse Docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#sessions) tells that old sessions are deleted when another user logs in the same device.

Comment: Every time that a User logs in, old sessions that match the same user and the same installation id are automatically destroyed. I guess that you are not saving Installation for Android (and don't have an installation id associated to the session) and that's why you see different behaviors.

Comment: It's not the same user. Let me explain clearly. Let's say I am logged in as User1 with installation id XYZ. Now I log in as User2 with installation id XYZ. Hence, the session should remain in iOS too as users are different. But the session is destroyed as soon as I logged into User2. And I checked Android have multiple sessions with same installation id and different users.

Comment: Someone raised the token for this issue [GitHub issue](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1569)